# segmentation fault (Core dumped) error on Dynamic array

Tags: c

I am having this issue when trying to build my dynamic array, I think that there is mystake on realloc function or something, would appreciate if you can give me a hand on it.
I am able to enter the names the first time but the issue start when Im doing it the second time

```
typedef struct {
      char nom[30], prenom[20];
      int age;

        } ITEM;

        void Lire(ITEM **items, int *nb_items)
        {
           int i = 0;

           printf("* Entrer les donnees et taper . pour terminer\n\n");

           for (i = 0; TRUE; i++) 
            {

                   ITEM *temp = (ITEM *) realloc(*items, ((i + 1) * sizeof(ITEM)));
                    if (temp == NULL)
                    {
                        free(*items);
                        printf("Il n'y a pas de memoire! \n");
                        exit (0);
                    }
                    *items = temp;
                    printf("> nom    : ");
                    scanf("%s", (*items[i]).nom);

                    if ((*items[i]).nom[0] == '.')
                    break;

                    printf("> prenom : ");
                    scanf("%s", (*items[i]).prenom);

            }
        }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   ITEM *items;
   int nb_items=0;
   items = (ITEM *) malloc(sizeof(ITEM));
   if(items == 0)
   {
       printf("Il n'y a pas de memoire! \n");
       exit (0);
   }
   Lire(&items, &nb_items);
   free (items);
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You tagged this question as `C++`.  Why are you not using `std::vector`?

Comment: You can´t use realloc alone. malloc and free are there to use too.

Comment: thanks, I am using them in the main this is just a function to fill my array, should I use malloc and free here as well?

Comment: Then start with telling us where the error occurs?

Comment: I can tape the first name, and family name, the problem starts when I am entering the second name

Comment: I leave below the main, hope it helps.

Comment: Are you typing a name that is too long? You are not protecting your strings from overrun. Try `scanf("%29s", (*items[i]).nom);`

Comment: I tape usually 2 or 3 caracters names and does not work, I will protect anyway, thanks

Comment: we saw this code yesterday :-) . Where is it failing now?

Comment: Actually `realloc` can work just fine without `malloc`/`free`. If the initial value `NULL`, `realloc` works as `malloc`. If the requested size is 0, `realloc` works as `free`.

Comment: @pm100 thanks :-), the issue now is when I am filling the dynamic array, I am able to enter the first namees but when I am entering the second this error appears. thanks is advance

Comment: seems that there is an issue on realloc function

Answer (score 2):

You problem is in operator precedence: `*items[i]` evaluates to `items[i][0]` and you want `items[0][i]`, which is:

```
(*items)[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Array subscript access binds tighter than `*`. This causes `*items[i]` to be interpreted as `*(items[i])`, for example in this statement:

```
scanf("%s", (*items[i]).nom);
```

So `items` is accessed as if it would be an array of pointers to `ITEM`. In reality it is a pointer to an array of `ITEM` structs, and should be accessed like this:

```
scanf("%s", (*items)[i].nom);
```

Answer (score 0):

to make life easier i would do

```
            *items = temp;
            ITEM *current = &temp[i];
            printf("> nom    : ");
            scanf("%s", current->nom);
            ...etc
```

makes the code easier to read and simplifies the whole operator precedence isuuse

Comment: actually this issue was solved today with your help, the names are being inserted into the array, the isse is reallocating memory I think as I am getting this segmentation Fault(Core dumped) when I need to enter the second block of info